# PHP: How to use preg_split and match data type

Tags: php, regex

I am new to regex. I am trying to check the parameter with it's data type and return the dynamic parameters and the original route in the array. I appreciate any help that can take me a small step. Thanks in advance.

```
$routes = array(
    "admin",
    "edit/{int:order_id}",
    "u/{string:uname}",
    "admin/edit/{int/id}"
);

$path = "edit/101";

function get_routes ( $routes, $path ) {
    foreach ( $routes as $route ) {
        if ( preg_split("[*{*:*}]", $route) == $path ) {

        }
    }

    //returns order_id => 101 and the route 'edit/{int:order_id}'
}
```

Comment: @JayBlanchard Thank you will do.

Comment: Now, for this question you need to be more clear. What results are you expecting?

Comment: @JayBlanchard I am expecting the parameter from the url to be matched to routes. eg: `edit/101` return `array( "order_id" => 101 )`

Comment: Does it have to use regex? Or would you be happy with other methods?

Comment: @JayBlanchard It's possible to use `str_replace` and remove the `{` and `}` and explode on `:` but I do not know how to move to next from there. Any other recommendations are welcome

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177045/discussion-between-slam-book-and-jay-blanchard).